# What is this code's space complexity

Tags: python, sorting

I'm not sure about the **space** complexity of these two selection sort implementations:

```
def selection_sort(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    for i in range(n):
        m_index = i 
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            if lst[m_index] > lst[j]:
                m_index = j
            swap(lst, i, m_index)
    return None
```

and this one:

```
def selection_sort2(lst):
    n = len(lst)
        for i in range(n):
            m = min(lst[i:n])
            m_index = lst.index(m) #find the index of the minimum
            lst[i], lst[m_index] = lst[m_index], lst[i]
    return None
```

and, regarding the second code, where are the previous slices being saved, once m gets a new slice?

Thanks!

Comment: provided that i have no idea what the space complexity of `swap` is, the first part seems to be O(n) because you only make a static number of extra variables

Comment: i think using slices like that allocates them memory, making the second solution worse than O(n)

Comment: Aren't both algorithms completely in-place (i.e. don't require any extra memory)?

Comment: `where are the previous slices being saved, once m gets a new slice?`  a) isn't `m` a single value (not a slice)?  b) why does the old value of `m` need to be saved?

Comment: Each `lst[i:n]` creatrs a new list. Thus, you will need `len(lst[0:n])` auxiliary memory...

Answer (score 0):

The first point to make is that your second function contains a bug in its use of `index`.  Running this:

```
def selection_sort2(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    for i in range(n):
        m = min(lst[i:n])
        m_index = lst.index(m) #find the index of the minimum
        lst[i], lst[m_index] = lst[m_index], lst[i]
    return

l = [5,4,1,3,4]
selection_sort2(l)
print(l)
```

prints out

```
[1, 3, 5, 4, 4]
```

This is because you have misunderstood the `index` function.  What it does is to find the first occurrence of the supplied value (here `m`) in the supplied list (here `lst`).  So what your code is doing is first of all to create a slice and find its `min`.  Then the slice goes out of scope and is garbage collected.  Then you find the value in the whole list (in the wrong place in this example).

We can fix this by restricting the index to the slice, though bear in mind that this is not good code, as I will explain next.

```
    m_index = lst.index(m,i) #find the index of the minimum
```

With this change, the function works, but it has two problems.  The first is that the slicing does (as you suspected) create a copy and so doubles the memory requirement of the code.  But the second problem is that once you find the minimum value, you then pointlessly iterate through the slice a second time to find the index of the place where you found the minimum, so also doubling the run time.

The copying can be fixed by replacing the slice with a generator expression.  So instead of a slice we just produce the values one at a time.

Then we can arrange to find the index of the minimum by carrying it along with the value in a tuple. Then minimising the tuples provides us with the index at the same time.  The resulting code looks like this:

```
def selection_sort2(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    for i in range(n):
        m,m_index = min((lst[j],j) for j in range(i,n))
        lst[i], lst[m_index] = lst[m_index], lst[i]
    return
```

However, this code is functionally more or less the same as your first example and probably not any clearer - so why change?